# Accidently made further commits during interactive rebase (edit)

Tags: git, shell, egit, rebase

I've started to fix a messed up commit by using interactive rebase (edit) in the shell but I've forgotten to continue the rebase.

Shell:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~1
[force edit on commit]
git commit --ammend
git reset ...
```

After that I just made further commits in eclipse (egit). How can I rescue these commits? Respectively what will happen with them when I just continue the rebase in the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rebase --continue will proceed where it stops, that is, it will replay the rest of the commits not yet rebased above your intermediate changes.

To rescue your intermediate commits, you can cherry-pick them, or even call rebase -i again.